# Assigning prior weights/preferences to predictor variables for regression tree analysis

Tags: r, regression, bayesian

Within R's "rpart" package for classification/regression trees, is it possible to specify prior weights for the predictor variables? Alternatively, is this a possibility with the BART (Bayesian Additive Regression Trees) package, random forests, or any other package in R?

Based on expert opinion, I would like to force certain predictor variables to be included. Thanks